# Prevent a method from being documented [PHPDOC / SAMI]

Tags: php, phpdoc

This is my first run at generating API documentation. I am playing around with Sami and phpdoc.

I would like to know how I can prevent a method from being documented ?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Don't put any documentation for it?

Answer (score 1):

In [phpdoc](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.ignore.pkg.html) it is done using the `@ignore` tag:

```
/**
 * @ignore
 */
function secret() {

}
```

Comment: Is it. I gave that a shot in SAMI does not seem to work. Let me try with PHPDOC